# Google Sheets Scripting -- Newbie

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I am missing the ***way** obvious
What is wrong with this script:

```
function setMenuChoices() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var cell = sheet.getRange("P28");
 If(cell == "X") cell.setValue(" ");
 else cell.setValue("X");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
If(cell == "X") cell.setValue(" ");
```

use

```
if(cell.getValue() == "X") cell.setValue(" ");
```

Comment: Please consider to accept my answer (click on the check mark) if it was useful for you (2 reputation for you).